# Warnings in hyperref

Tags: hyperref, warnings, greek

I am struggling to use links inside my text using `\usepackage{hyperref}` but after the compile I take a tone of warnings. Could you help please?

Have a look at my code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{extarrows} %για να γράφω πανω από συνεπαγωγές 
\usepackage{hyperref}


\newcommand{\rightarrowdbl}{\rightarrow\mathrel{\mkern-14mu}\rightarrow} % για να γραφω πανω απο βελη επιμορφισμων
\newcommand{\xrightarrowdbl}[2][]{%
  \xrightarrow[#1]{#2}\mathrel{\mkern-14mu}\rightarrow
}


\sloppy %Ρυθμίζει τα overfull/underfile στις γραμμές!


%Φτιάχνει το μέγεθος της γραμματοσειράς μέσα στα math enviroments δηλαδή μέσα στα δολάρια. Το πρώτο bracket είναι για το κείμενο και το δεύτερο για τα δολάρια. Δες και https://texfaq.org/FAQ-mathsize
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{13}{7}{5}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\makeatletter

% Define amsthm theorems first
\newtheorem{defin}{Ορισμός}[section] % Creates a new counter, number within section
\newtheorem{prt}[defin]{Παρατήρηση} % Putting [defin] in second position uses defin's counter instead of creating a new one
\newtheorem{prts}[defin]{Παρατηρήσεις} % Again share defin's counter
\newtheorem{exmp}[defin]{Παράδειγμα} % etc.
\newtheorem{exmps}[defin]{Παραδείγματα}
\newtheorem*{simiosi}{Σημείωση}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter*=defin, number within=section]{mytheo}{Θεώρημα}%
{colback=black!5,colframe=red!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th
\newtcbtheorem[use counter*=defin, number within=section]{myprop}{Πρόταση}%
{colback=black!5,colframe=red!50!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter*=defin, number within=section]{mylem}{Λήμμα}%
{colback=black!5,colframe=red!50!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter*=defin, number within=section]{mypor}{Πόρισμα}%
{colback=black!5,colframe=red!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter*=defin, number within=section]{myax}{Αξίωμα}%
{colback=black!5,colframe=blue!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{udidot}
\usepackage{calrsfs}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\newcommand{\Bb}{\mathbb}
\newcommand{\tle}{\trianglelefteq}
\newcommand{\properideal}{%
  \mathrel{\ooalign{$\lneq$\cr\raise.22ex\hbox{$\lhd$}\cr}}}
\newcommand{\Ker}{\mathrm{Ker}}
\newcommand{\kdim}{\mathrm{Krulldim}}
\newcommand{\spec}{\mathrm{Spec}}
\newcommand{\mspec}{\mathrm{Maxpec}}
\newcommand{\rad}{\mathrm{Rad}}
\newcommand{\nrad}{\mathrm{Nilrad}}
\newcommand{\jac}{\mathrm{Jac}}
\raggedbottom
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{mylm}{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{mylm}{\end{minipage}\par}
\usepackage{calrsfs}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\newcommand{\La}{\mathcal{L}}
\newcommand{\Lb}{\pazocal{L}}
\newcommand{\Fb}{\pazocal{F}}
\newcommand{\Pb}{\pazocal{P}}
\begin{document}
\title{\Huge{Το Θεώρημα των \\ \latintext Hopkins - Levitzki \greektext}}
\author{\Large{ασδφ}\\  ΑΠΘ}
\maketitle{} 
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Πρώτα και Μέγιστα Ιδεώδη}
\section{Μέγιστα ιδεώδη}  
\begin{myprop}[label=krmegid]{Κριτήριο Μέγιστων Ιδεωδών}{}
Έστω $R$ 
ιλθυηβξν
\end{myprop}
Από την Πρόταση \ref{krmegid}
\end{document}
```

Some of the warnings are in the following picture.

[image]

Comment: Please show us the first complete error message you got in your answer!

Comment: That warnings mean that the greek letters are not displayable in bookmarks. Please check the documentation of hyperref, chapter 4.1.2: " Replacement macros hyperref takes the text for bookmarks from the arguments of commands like \section, which can contain things like math, colors, or font changes, none of which will display in bookmarks as is." You need to use  `\texorpdfstring{TEXstring}{PDFstring}` ... I'm simply not sure that `hyperref` can handle greek language ...

Comment: Or you have to load another class for greek text (sorry, I do not speak greek and can you not help you there).

Comment: I have tried with this. The errors are only 2: Font shape `PU/udidot/m/n' undefined(Font) using `PU/pdf/m/n' instead and Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted. But still exist... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some changings in your given code (I marked them with `<=======` in the following MWE) I can compile without errors and warnings, but please see it only as a hack, because I simply commented `\frontmatter` (and therefore `\mainmatter`) to get rid of the roman numbering of frontmatter part.

I changed the order of calling `hyperref` (should be called last in your case) and corrected errors in the title (command `\Huge` and `\Large` do not take arguments, use them like `{\Huge text to be huge}`).

Please see the code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <============================================
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{extarrows} %για να γράφω πανω από συνεπαγωγές 

\newcommand{\rightarrowdbl}{\rightarrow\mathrel{\mkern-14mu}\rightarrow} % για να γραφω πανω απο βελη επιμορφισμων
\newcommand{\xrightarrowdbl}[2][]{%
  \xrightarrow[#1]{#2}\mathrel{\mkern-14mu}\rightarrow
}

\sloppy %Ρυθμίζει τα overfull/underfile στις γραμμές!

%Φτιάχνει το μέγεθος της γραμματοσειράς μέσα στα math enviroments δηλαδή μέσα στα δολάρια. Το πρώτο bracket είναι για το κείμενο και το δεύτερο για τα δολάρια. Δες και https://texfaq.org/FAQ-mathsize
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{13}{7}{5}

\theoremstyle{definition}

% Define amsthm theorems first
\newtheorem{defin}{Ορισμός}[section] % Creates a new counter, number within section
\newtheorem{prt}[defin]{Παρατήρηση} % Putting [defin] in second position uses defin's counter instead of creating a new one
\newtheorem{prts}[defin]{Παρατηρήσεις} % Again share defin's counter
\newtheorem{exmp}[defin]{Παράδειγμα} % etc.
\newtheorem{exmps}[defin]{Παραδείγματα}
\newtheorem*{simiosi}{Σημείωση}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter*=defin, number within=section]{mytheo}{Θεώρημα}%
{colback=black!5,colframe=red!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th} % <=====================
\newtcbtheorem[use counter*=defin, number within=section]{myprop}{Πρόταση}%
{colback=black!5,colframe=red!50!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter*=defin, number within=section]{mylem}{Λήμμα}%
{colback=black!5,colframe=red!50!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter*=defin, number within=section]{mypor}{Πόρισμα}%
{colback=black!5,colframe=red!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter*=defin, number within=section]{myax}{Αξίωμα}%
{colback=black!5,colframe=blue!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{udidot}

\usepackage{calrsfs}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref} % <======================================

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\newcommand{\Bb}{\mathbb}
\newcommand{\tle}{\trianglelefteq}
\newcommand{\properideal}{%
  \mathrel{\ooalign{$\lneq$\cr\raise.22ex\hbox{$\lhd$}\cr}}}
\newcommand{\Ker}{\mathrm{Ker}}
\newcommand{\kdim}{\mathrm{Krulldim}}
\newcommand{\spec}{\mathrm{Spec}}
\newcommand{\mspec}{\mathrm{Maxpec}}
\newcommand{\rad}{\mathrm{Rad}}
\newcommand{\nrad}{\mathrm{Nilrad}}
\newcommand{\jac}{\mathrm{Jac}}

\raggedbottom

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{mylm}{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{mylm}{\end{minipage}\par}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\newcommand{\La}{\mathcal{L}}
\newcommand{\Lb}{\pazocal{L}}
\newcommand{\Fb}{\pazocal{F}}
\newcommand{\Pb}{\pazocal{P}}


\begin{document}

\title{\Huge Το Θεώρημα των \\ \latintext Hopkins - Levitzki \greektext} % <==========
\author{{\Large ασδφ}\\  ΑΠΘ} % <=======================================
\maketitle{} 
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

%\frontmatter % <============================ resulting in roman numbers
\tableofcontents

%\mainmatter % <========================================================
\chapter{Πρώτα και Μέγιστα Ιδεώδη}
\section{Μέγιστα ιδεώδη}  
\begin{myprop}[label=krmegid]{Κριτήριο Μέγιστων Ιδεωδών}{}
Έστω $R$ 
ιλθυηβξν
\end{myprop}
Από την Πρόταση \ref{krmegid}

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: greek page]

Comment: Now works fine! So, this was a result form the first (i), (ii), etc pages? Do you mean that this is the hack?

Comment: @Chris Yes, the last two warnings results from the usage of roman numbers  `i` (idot) and `ii` which are not defined in greek. Commenting `\frontmatter` deactivated the roman numbering, commenting `\mainmatter` deactivated the reset of the page counter to 1 (which would cause other errors!). I'm sure there is a way around that hack, but I do not know it, I have no experience with greek ;-)

Comment: Thank you for all this useful information! I ll keep this hack in my notes! :D

Comment: And now I face a new problem! When I use English in the title of chapters or in "enumerate with (i)"! :'(

Comment: @Chris Can you please ask a new question with a new MWE including english text? Reduce the code in the MWE to only that part that is needed for the issue. Theorems, TikZ etc can be omitted. They did not influence the given issue in this question too.

Answer (score 2):

Use hyperref with the option `unicode`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Πρώτα και Μέγιστα Ιδεώδη}
\section{Μέγιστα ιδεώδη}
Από την Πρόταση \ref{krmegid}
\end{document}
```

This will give correct bookmarks:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What if we want to use English in \chapter{blahblah} ?

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question with a suitable minimal example.  The comments are not the right place.